# Calculate the big-O and big-Omega of the following piece of code

Tags: complexity-theory

I was asked to find the big-O and Big-Omega if I know that function **f** has **O(log(n)), Ω(1)** and function **g** has **O(n), Ω((log(n))^2)**

```
for (int i = n; i >= 0; i/=2)
if (f(i) <= g(i))
    for (int j = f(i)*f(i); j < n; j++)
        f(j);
```

The big problem that I have is that I don't know how to incorporate the complexity of the funstions in the calculation. I mean I know how to calculate the complexity of loops that looks like this:

```
for(int i =0 ; i< n*2; i++) {
   ....
}
```

or like  this

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {

     }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

This is what I've tried:

```
for (int i = n; i >= 0; i/=2)// this is aproximatly O(log(n))
if (f(i) <= g(i))// because O(n) < O(log(n)) this line is O(n)
    for (int j = f(i)*f(i); j < n; j++)// O(n*log(n))
        f(j);// O(log(n))
```

So by my calculation I get O(log(n)*n *n *log(n)*log(n))=O(n^2*log^3(n))

Comment: Could be the wrong place to ask. BTW don't expect us to do your homework and show us what you tried and understood

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky question, because the loop execution depends on values, returned by functions `f` and `g`. However remember, that you need to estimate the *worst case* - so you need to assume two things:

- `f(i) <= g(i)` is always true, so the internal loop always executes
- the internal loop starts from `0`, because it's a minimal value, which you can get as a result of squaring the `f(i)` value

So, your piece of code becomes much simpler:

```
for (int i = n; i >= 0; i/=2)
{
  f(i);
  g(i);
  f(i);
  f(i);
  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    f(j);
}
```

I think you can take over from here.

Comment: Do I for the big Omega need to estimate the best case?

Comment: Yes, that's right. In the best case the internal loop won't run at all